# Changing focal length of diode-based laser

Tags: optics, laser, lenses

I have a blue laser diode that has a focal length of about 2cm. I would like to extend that, so I can engrave things further from the laser, and to lenghten the distance where the beam is focused enough to be suitable for engraving and cutting.

So far I've learned that this could be possible with concave lenses; what should I know and/or calculate before I go looking for one? Any requirements for the kind of glass, etc?

Comment: Your laser is basically monochromatic, which means that a single lens is sufficient. Ideally you would use lenses with optical coating that reduces reflections for your blue wavelength, otherwise you will lose 5% or more in laser power.

Comment: I suppose that the laser is currently able to do engraving, but you don't say.  You wouldn't be asking the question if that weren't the case.  Note that the size of the focus spot will be larger if you make the focal length longer.  As a consequence, the intensity will be lower.   A larger spot and lower intensity might give you unexpected and possibly unwanted results.   Only trying will tell.

Comment: As the focal length increases, the focal point becomes more elongated. This means your depth of field will increase at the expense of power density as pointed out by @garyp

Comment: Yes, it's able to do engraving. I did not realize that making the light "cone" longer will also make the dot bigger, and as a consequence lower the power per area. I guess I need a better laser. Thanks for your help!